# Does firebase analytics work while development on localhost?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I've tried to follow everything from the docs.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=web

This is how I'm initializing my `firebase` app on my client code:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/functions';
import 'firebase/storage';

// .env file in root folder
const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Do I need to call `firebase.analytics();` ?

So far I'm only running in my localhost. I have not deployed yet to Firebase Hosting.

Should I be able to see myself as a user on the [Analytics Console](https://analytics.google.com/)?

How does it work? Do I need to log something to see the users accessing my web app?

So far, nothing shows up.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

I just found out that I need to import firebase analytics, like

```
import 'firebase/analytics';
```

But I still didn't get if I need to cal `firebase.analytics();`. Does anybody know that?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to call `firebase.analytics();`?

Without a call to `firebase.analytics()` to initialize the analytics module, no events will be logged. So if you want to use Firebase analytics in your app, you'll indeed need to call `firebase.analytics()` when the app starts.